# How to display a datepicker with nativescript

Tags: android, layout, datepicker, nativescript

I want to display a datepicker using Nativescript on android but i did not find how to do. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/d722071748bb5e1badcb8f383858341c9ffb3b00/apps/gallery-app/views

```
<DatePicker day="15" month="5" year="2015" verticalAlignment="center" horizontalAlignment="center"/>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked well, another thing do you know how to get the value of the day, year and month from the datepicker, i've tried that : viewModule.getViewById( page, "date" ).year ( i put the id="date" in the datepicker) but it dit not work.